# Validate the correct month in C

Tags: c

I am working in this program which is very easy but I am having trouble validating the input user, I do not know how to get the correct output from the user. The program says to get the date of last oil change (month and year).
  Perform input validation and request the user enter correct values when input is incorrect.
This is what I have so far, and I don`t know if what I got so far is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int month, year;

    // Enter the date of last oil change and Validate the correct month value

    printf("Enter the Date of last oil change, month (1-12): ");
    scanf("%i", &month);

    if (month > 0 && month <= 12)
    {
        printf("Month: %i\n ", month );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Please enter a number between 1-12.\n " );
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I think the question is how to make sure the input for scanf is the correct type.

Comment: You should get the year as well, and make sure it's not higher than the current year. And if it is the current year, make sure the month is less than the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this instead:

```
int main(void)
{
int month, year;

// Enter the date of last oil change and Validate the correct month value

printf("Enter the Date of last oil change, month (1-12): ");
//Add a space before %i to disregard whitespace.
scanf(" %i", &month);

while (month < 1 || month > 12)
    {
        printf( "Please enter a number between 1-12.\n " );
        scanf(" %i", &month);
    }

printf("Month: %i\n ", month );

return(0);
}
```

This way the program keeps asking the user for a value until a correct one is entered.

Comment: Should it not be `month > 12`?

Comment: Depends on how you use the value. I guessed eventually it would be used to fetch something from an array, which is indexed starting at 0.

Comment: But since the user is entering months 1-12, that will require subtracting 1 later. The input should be 1-based.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is keep asking to the user for the correct value of year and month, this is a way to achieve that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int month = 0;
            int year = 0;
    // Enter the date of last oil change and Validate the correct month value

    printf("Enter the Date of last oil change, month (1-12): ");
    scanf("%d", &month);

    while(month <= 0 || month > 12) { //loop until the values are correct
        printf("Please enter a number between 1-12: \n");
        scanf("%d", &month);
    }

    printf("Enter the Year of last oil change:");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    while(year <= 0) { //same here (the years must be positive)
        printf("Please enter a positive number to be a year\n");
        scanf("%d", &year);
    }

    return 0;
}
```